# How to return data from function

Tags: node.js, express, promise, es6-promise

I have function like this:

```
export function getAllUser() {
  let user;
  UserModel
    .find()
    .exec()
    .then((data) => {
      return data;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return err;
    });
}
```

How can I return data from this function? For example, I want to defind:
`user = getAllUser()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as you are working with promises, you have to return the promise and treat it outside:

```
export function getAllUser() {
  let user;
  return UserModel
    .find()
    .exec()
    .then((data) => {
      return data;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return err;
    });
}

getAllUser()
.then(data => {
  // here you can access data
});
```

Comment: Thank @David, can you more specific how to use data from promise? In the example, you mean I call a function and assign data to variable inside `.then()`?

Comment: That's how promises work. When you call a function that return a promise, if you want to work with the value that is returned in the inside of the promise, you are going to get it into .then(

Try the code I wrote and check it, and tell me if it works.

Comment: it work find. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could use async/await like:

```
export async function getAllUser(){
  return await UserModel.find().exec();
}
```